# Primefaces data exporter from data table with dynamic columns

Tags: primefaces, datatable, export-to-excel, dynamic-columns, exporter

Has anyone used primefaces data exporter component successfully with primefaces datatable with dynamic columns?

In my case, it generates the excel file but it is empty.

But if I keep everything same and just normal datatable instead of datatable with dynamic columns, the generated excel file is not empty.

I am trying to see if somebody has done this.

```
<p:dataExporter />
and
<p:dataTable /> //(with dynamic columns)
```

It works fine if I don't use the dynamic columns.

I am using PrimeFaces 2.2.1, JSF 2.0, poi-3.2-FINAL.jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry but this is not currently supported for the `dataExporter` component.

http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=12133&p=38149&hilit=dataExporter+dynamic#p38149

This is coming straight from Cagatay Civici, lead developer on the Primefaces project.

Comment: Thank you. I asked this question yesterday but I don't why he didn't tell me anything. http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14322&p=43239#p43239. Anyways thanks, atleast now I know that I need to go look some other workout for this.

Comment: PrimeFaces 3.4 supports exporting p:columns.

Comment: @CagatayCivici Cool, Primefaces keeps getting better and better!  Keep up the great work guys!