# primefaces export data table dynamic columns

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

i want to add exporting for dynamic columns.
I think that should go. [Dynamic Columns Export Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002976/primefaces-data-exporter-problem-with-data-table-with-dynamic-columns)

I used the samplecode from Primefaces and edit it: [Primefaces Example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/exporter.jsf)
The Code works, but the data isn't correct.
The File include the dynamic Data like `data[i], data[i], ....` and not the attributes in data[i].

Any idea?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
      xmlns:my="http://java.dynamic.list.de"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<ui:composition template="META-INF/templates/Template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">      
            <h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
              <h:panelGrid columns="3"> 
                  <h:selectOneMenu id="showColl" value= "#{searchBean.collList.currentColl}" rendered = "#{searchBean.search.visible}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{searchBean.collList.collList}" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>

             <h:outputText value="#{msgs.collection}" rendered = "#{searchBean.search.hide}"></h:outputText>
             <h:outputText value="#{searchBean.collList.currentColl}" rendered = "#{searchBean.search.hide}"></h:outputText>
             <h:commandButton id="show" action="#{searchBean.showFieldList}" value="#{msgs.plus}" rendered="#{searchBean.search.visible}" style=""/>    
                          <h:commandButton id="hide" action="#{searchBean.hideFieldList}" value="#{msgs.minus}" rendered="#{searchBean.search.hide}" immediate="true" onchange="this.form.submit()" style=""/>                                   
             </h:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGrid columns="1" rendered="#{searchBean.search.hide}"> 
             <h:panelGrid columns="2"> 
                <h:outputLabel value="#{msgs.Attr}"></h:outputLabel> 
                 <h:selectOneMenu id="Field"                 
                             value="#{searchBean.collList.currentField}"
                             rendered="#{searchBean.search.readWrite}">
                             <f:selectItems
                               value="#{searchBean.collList.fieldList}" />
                          </h:selectOneMenu>
                           <h:outputText value="#{searchBean.collList.currentField}" rendered="#{searchBean.search.readOnly}"></h:outputText>   
             </h:panelGrid>

             <h:panelGrid columns="2"> 
                 <h:outputLabel value="#{msgs.value}"></h:outputLabel> 
                 <h:inputText value="#{searchBean.search.value}"  rendered = "#{searchBean.search.readWrite}"></h:inputText>    
                 <h:outputText value="#{searchBean.search.value}" rendered = "#{searchBean.search.readOnly}"></h:outputText>
             </h:panelGrid>
             <h:panelGrid columns="3">
              <h:outputText value="#{msgs.sort_Order}"/>
                         <h:selectOneRadio id="sortOrder" 
                                value="#{searchBean.search.ascendingData}"                         
                                immediate="true" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msgs.ascending}" itemValue="a" itemDisabled="#{searchBean.search.readOnly}"/>
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msgs.descending}" itemValue="d" itemDisabled="#{searchBean.search.readOnly}"/>
                         </h:selectOneRadio>
            </h:panelGrid>   
            </h:panelGrid>       
             <h:commandButton id="search" action="#{searchBean.searchButton}" value="#{msgs.search}" style=""/>

    <p:dataTable id="datas" var="data" value="#{searchBean.readListMap.items}" style="width:150px"
                 scrollable="true" scrollWidth="800" scrollHeight="400" emptyMessage="Keine Daten vorhanden">  
        <p:columns value="#{searchBean.collList.fieldListColumns}" var="columnName" columnIndexVar="i" style="width:150px"  headerText="#{columnName}">         
            #{data[i]}
        </p:columns>  

    </p:dataTable>                           

        <h:commandLink>   
            <p:graphicImage library="images" name="csv.png" /> 
            <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="datas" fileName="assetDB" />  
        </h:commandLink>  

        <h:commandLink>  
            <p:graphicImage library="images" name="xml.png" /> 
            <p:dataExporter type="xml" target="datas" fileName="assetDB" />  
        </h:commandLink>  

    </h:form>                
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

Comment: Show your xhtml page please.

Comment: What version of primefaces are you using? Anyhow, you will need to use CustomExporter to do what you want.

Comment: I use primefaces 4.0. I guess that i need a CustomExporter. The problem is, that i have a NoSQL-Database. This mean my data has no Shema e.g diffrent columns. This is the reason why i use dynamic columns. I i create an export of my data in my data table i have columns with null, because the data hasn't his columns. But if i export the data in cvs i have one header row with all columns and the rest of rows are the data. I can only create a export for one schema in my database. I need diffrent export cvs files for diffrent shemas. Is my idea correct?

Comment: To import the data with the same columns. I can made this like to build the tabel with dynamic columns. The diffrent is that i don't fill a table, but a string e.g. string builder to create my export file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this code toe create the file.
result i a StringBuilder to create your costum string. i created a specific cvs file.

```
String tempString = result.toString();
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(tempString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
Timestamp tstamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "application/cvs", "test-"+tstamp+".cvs");
```

I write in the xhtml file the example from primefaces [Primefaces example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileDownload.jsf). Hope this helps other people to have problems with dynamic columns and primefaces to export the data.